# Internal Server Error Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am currently setting up a Heroku deployment. Everything works fine when it is run locally but I get the following error from Heroku.

```
at=info method=GET path="/" host=pure-cliffs-68507.herokuapp.com 
request_id=66cd6aa8-209d-4065-88ce-ad201ce6e713 fwd="210.86.90.97" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=524 protocol=https
2017-07-03T15:05:22.180020+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 500 19ms - 148b
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181519+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to lookup view " index.html" in views directory "/app"
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181520+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.render  (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/routes.js:8:7
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181522+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181522+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181523+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181523+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181524+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181525+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2017-07-03T15:05:22.181525+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

I beleive it is something to do with the file paths. I currently have everything in the base directory (ie project/) and therefore am using the following.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
app.set('views', __dirname);
```

Here are some of my get requests

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html'); 
});

app.get('/browsePage', function(req, res) {
    res.render('browsePage.html'); 

});
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't render `html` pages in `node.js`. You can try sending `html` files:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('index.html'); 
});

app.get('/browsePage', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('browsePage.html'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to lookup view " index.html" in views directory "/app"

If your code working on local, Do you can check your path again? 
And it's should be:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../public'));
```

btw, you should use any template to render view(jade,..) https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html